# Using operator.itemgetter to handle dictionary sorting

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

Referring to the below code, the first for loop can be easily used for the sorting in the dictionary and it works very well.

```
import operator

myExample = {'Item1': 3867, 'Item2': 20, 'Item3': 400, 'Item4': 100, 'Item5': 2870,
             'Item6': 22, 'Item7': 528, 'Item8': 114}

for w in sorted(myExample, key=myExample.get, reverse=False):
    print w, myExample[w]

print ("\n")

for w in sorted(myExample, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print w, myExample[w]
```

But somehow I was told by the other thread, it is advice to use `operator.itemgetter(index)` method to perform the sorting due to the efficiency reason. But the second for loop is never works in my case.

Perhaps I should go through the documentation first and this is what I get:

```
>>> itemgetter(1)('ABCDEFG')
'B'

>>> itemgetter(1,3,5)('ABCDEFG')
('B', 'D', 'F')

>>> itemgetter(slice(2,None))('ABCDEFG')
'CDEFG'
```

The example is simple, But to be honest, I don't know how to link this back to the dictionary case. How should I use the index inside the itemgetter and different index will have what kind of impact? I tried all index from 0 to 4 and none of them give me an ascending sorting result and error will occur starting from index 5.

In a document, there is a example for tuple case, but it's not works for the dictionary.

```
>>> inventory = [('apple', 3), ('banana', 2), ('pear', 5), ('orange', 1)]

>>> getcount = itemgetter(1)

>>> map(getcount, inventory)

[3, 2, 5, 1]

>>> sorted(inventory, key=getcount)

[('orange', 1), ('banana', 2), ('apple', 3), ('pear', 5)]
```

Back to the Origin, I still hope to understand how to use the index inside the itemgetter and what it does in different cases like tuple vs. dictionary vs. list vs. only a string vs. tuple inside a list, and etc.

Please advise.

Comment: you need `myExample.items()` in the first case. that gives you a list of tuples. itemgetter[0] gets the first item of the tuple, hwich is the key, as per `items()`

Comment: and you would be iterating on tuples, so no need for `print myExample[w]`, `print w` is enough

Comment: to be a little clearer: you can't sort a dictionary, you can only sort it's items, which are a list of tuples. (`dict.items()`). Iterating directly on a dict actually iterates on the keys (same as `dict.keys()`).

Comment: Hi @njzk2 , it does not help after i change to below code (i use index 0,1,2,3,4) as well

for w in sorted(myExample.keys, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):

Comment: I think i know what is the problem.
Thanks for the advice...My take away here is operator.itemgetter cant be used for dictionary sorting. So, i must convert it to tuple first before sorting.

Comment: Hi @njzk2 , May i know the "key=operator.itemgetter(0)" method is better than the "key=myExample.get" method?

What make this 2 have significant differences in term of performance wise?

Comment: I don't find one better than the other. The first is used to sort keys according to the values, the second one to sort by nth item, which can be used for more things (sort dict by key, by value, sort list of tuples by arbitrary element or slice of elements...)